# How to download and rewrite a file in Python?

Tags: python

[The link to the code is here (didn´t copy it here to give the guy credit):](http://investorhacks.tumblr.com/)

I don´t want it to change the name with the date as is currently doing, but to download the file "finviz.csv" and rewrite it each day (with the scheduler task) to keep the data updated in my data system.

I´ve tried some tweaks, but I´m no developer I don´t have a clue how to do it.
Can you please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments in the code described it quite clearly:

```
# we're going to name the file by the date it was downloaded (e.g. 2012-3-18.csv)
fname = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")+".csv";
```

So just change the line to

```
fname = "finviz.csv";
```

And fix the file existence check logic:

```
# check if the file does not already exist
if not os.path.isfile(savepath+"/"+fname):
    # open a file to save the data to ("wb" means write binary mode)
    outfile = open(savepath+"/"+fname, "wb");
    # download the data from the url specified above
    infile = urllib2.urlopen(url);
    # read the downloaded data and write it to our output file
    outfile.write(infile.read());
    # close the output file once we're done
    outfile.close();
else:
    print "'"+fname+"' ALREADY EXISTS in the save directory '"+savepath+"'.";
```

to:

```
# open a file to save the data to ("wb" means write binary mode)
outfile = open(savepath+"/"+fname, "wb");
# download the data from the url specified above
infile = urllib2.urlopen(url);
# read the downloaded data and write it to our output file
outfile.write(infile.read());
# close the output file once we're done
outfile.close();
```

Comment: Cool, thanks. I´ve done this, but I have to wait till Monday to see if it rewrites it..

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the line

```
fname = now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")+".csv";
```

for

```
fname = "finviz.csv";
```

And you also need to delete this `if` (and its corresponding `else`):

```
if not os.path.isfile(savepath+"/"+fname):
```